# Why can't I reference JavaScript files in my View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reference, master-pages, partial-views

My JS works when I reference it in the MasterPage, and it works when I reference it in a Partial View (`.ascx`), but not when I reference from the View (`.aspx`).

Any ideas why?

Comment: Generally you can reference javascript in your View files just like in any other that you mentioned. What kind of js error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error at all - what I get is no functionality.

Comment: How is it rendering when it hits the browser?  Is there something in the URL for the .js file(s) on the .aspx that's different from the others?

Comment: After re-reading your question, it's not clear to me from your description exactly what your setup is. (1) do you have the script tag included in your masterpage? (2) when you say reference it in `x`, do you mean that you can use functions and variables declared in global scope in the script file included in the master page within `x`?

Comment: Can you share some code? The question is not very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the path to the script file correct in your View?

If you inspect HTTP traffic with something like Fiddler or Firebug's Net tab, do you see your script resources being downloaded to the browser?

You might want to use **[`UrlHelper.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)** and the relative path to render the script source in the page or perhaps create a `HtmlHelper` extension method to render out a script tag for you (I think one exists in **[MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)** if you're using that already).

Comment: If the masterpage can call it, and the file is included from the master page, then they should all three be able to call it. but if the block is being included in each place inline, then I would expect it to break.

Comment: Re-referencing the same js file is going to cause issues in the future. Law of unintended consequences.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest re-referencing the same script twice in a page, as there's the possibility that variable values could be overwritten when the second copy of the script code executes, possibly causing issues. It wasn't clear to me what the OP meant by referencing a script, so I posted a comment to get clarification.

Comment: And yet he already marked the question as answered, and so likely doesn't care anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a block declared in an included file (let's just pretend it looks like)

```
function alertMe(someValue) {
  alert(somevalue);
}
```

and in your master page, aspx, and ascx you have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alertMe("some string");
</script>
```

and it works in the master page and the ascx but not the aspx?

Comment: No, it's a request for clarification of the original question, which included NO code blocks. So you are correct.